# It is possible to obtain infrared NIR bands/channel of an image? (like as we get image's RGB channel)

Tags: python, c++, image

Here is code for getting RGB channels from an image.

```
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    Mat img = imread("aaa.png");
    namedWindow("image", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("image", img);

    Mat bgr[3];   //destination array
    split(img, bgr);//split source  

    //Note: OpenCV uses BGR color order
    imwrite("blue.png", bgr[0]); //blue channel
    imwrite("green.png", bgr[1]); //green channel
    imwrite("red.png", bgr[2]); //red channel
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

**Can we get NIR channel/bands from an image?.**

Comment: Most cameras have an NIR filter over the sensor to stop stray wavelengths. You normally need to have that removed by a specialist camera shop (Google *"Infrared conversion"*) or buy a camera like the *"NOIR Raspberry Pi Camera"*.

Comment: https://thepihut.com/products/raspberry-pi-noir-camera-module?gclid=CjwKCAiAgc-ABhA7EiwAjev-jyM3C-FuSrPYV9CdjwL8gEyYxNhp3A9GEFe1hkMfiv-vnE0RAVyEFhoCA8UQAvD_BwE

Comment: https://www.amateurphotographer.co.uk/technique/expert_advice/converting-an-older-camera-to-infrared-141068

Answer (score 0):

Typical RGB cameras only acquire RGB data -- there is no NIR collected directly.  You would need an NIR camera and then it would typically produce a single channel "grayscale" image made of an NIR sampled image.

Typical CCD and CMOS cameras are often naturally sensitive to Infrared light, and for this reason, they may have IR cut filters that block the IR light from being sensed on the imaging sensor to reduce distortion, but not always.

If you have more info on your camera, I'd be interested to take a look with you and see what specs it has.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question how your NIR channel is stored. I will assume it is the 4th channel in the PNG file. Please clarify if I have misunderstood.

A PNG file can store 4 channels (R,G,B,Alpha) with 8 or 16 bits per channel. I guess you could use the alpha channel as a way to store NIR intensity (instead of transparency) together with RGB. Normal PNG viewer applications will wrongly interpret the NIR color as transparency in this case.

OpenCV can load PNG with 4 channels. See a previous SO answer:

[How to load png images with 4 channels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803888/how-to-load-png-images-with-4-channels)

I guess the split function will work the same and produce 4 Mats, that you can save as separate images.

If your goal is to work with images with more channels than just color (e.g. R,G,B,Depth,Intensity,IR,UV) then perhaps look at some alternative image file formats. TIFF image files can store extra channels (a.k.a. ExtraSamples).

OpenCV does not natively support extra channels in a TIFF, but see this SO answer about how you can still load multi channel TIFFs into OpenCV by using libtif.

[OpenCv Multispectral Image openCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720778/opencv-multispectral-image-opencv)